# Convert XML to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I want to convert XML to a pandas DataFrame. I used the `ElementTree` library to parse the XML.

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

xtree = et.parse('xmlfile.xml)
xroot = xtree.getroot() 

[elem.tag for elem in xroot.iter()]
```

How do I access the values of each tag so that I can convert the XML to a pandas dataframe?

The Dataframe should look like this:

[image: Dataframe]

Using the following XML for the example, can you come up with some Python code to realise the above DataFrame?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Deze grammatica wordt niet meer gebruikt. Gebruik voortaan FMPXMLRESULT. -->

-<FMPDSORESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">

<ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>

<DATABASE>FrontEnd.fmp12</DATABASE>

<LAYOUT/>


-<ROW RECORDID="183122" MODID="0">

<identificatie>GAC</identificatie>

<naam>sample_naam_1</naam>

<wachtwoord>ww</wachtwoord>

<kenmerk>km</kenmerk>

<timestamp>30-4-2020 13:51:05</timestamp>

<berichtversie>1.0</berichtversie>

<analysecode>BST200428</analysecode>

<datum>30-4-2020</datum>

<datumontvangst>28-4-2020</datumontvangst>


</ROW>


-<ROW RECORDID="183123" MODID="0">

<identificatie>GAC</identificatie>

<naam>sample_naam_2</naam>

<wachtwoord>ww</wachtwoord>

<kenmerk>km</kenmerk>

<timestamp>30-4-2020 13:51:05</timestamp>

<berichtversie>1.0</berichtversie>

<analysecode>BST200429</analysecode>

<datum>30-4-2020</datum>

<datumontvangst>28-4-2020</datumontvangst>


</ROW>

</FMPDSORESULT>
```

Comment: ur data is not properly formatted. kindly recheck

Comment: Sorry I didn't fully copy the XML, i just changed it

Comment: still giving me errors - for instance ur layout section has an end without a related beginning ... i'm not sure what other errors are. to be on the safe side, run this stretch of data as a string and see if it gives any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) to parse your XML and then create a dataframe.

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import xmltodict

data = """
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<FMPDSORESULT xmlns='http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult'>
<ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
<DATABASE>FrontEnd.fmp12</DATABASE>
<LAYOUT/>
<ROW RECORDID='183122' MODID='0'>
<identificatie>GAC</identificatie>
<naam>sample_naam_1</naam>
<wachtwoord>ww</wachtwoord>
<kenmerk>km</kenmerk>
<timestamp>30-4-2020 13:51:05</timestamp>
<berichtversie>1.0</berichtversie>
<analysecode>BST200428</analysecode>
<datum>30-4-2020</datum>
<datumontvangst>28-4-2020</datumontvangst>
</ROW>
<ROW RECORDID='183123' MODID='0'>
<identificatie>GAC</identificatie>
<naam>sample_naam_2</naam>
<wachtwoord>ww</wachtwoord>
<kenmerk>km</kenmerk>
<timestamp>30-4-2020 13:51:05</timestamp>
<berichtversie>1.0</berichtversie>
<analysecode>BST200429</analysecode>
<datum>30-4-2020</datum>
<datumontvangst>28-4-2020</datumontvangst>
</ROW>
</FMPDSORESULT>
"""

parsed = xmltodict.parse(data.strip())
df = pd.DataFrame(parsed["FMPDSORESULT"]["ROW"])
display(df)
```

This prints out:

```
    @RECORDID   @MODID  identificatie   naam    wachtwoord  kenmerk     timestamp   berichtversie   analysecode     datum   datumontvangst
0   183122  0   GAC     sample_naam_1   ww  km  30-4-2020 13:51:05  1.0     BST200428   30-4-2020   28-4-2020
1   183123  0   GAC     sample_naam_2   ww  km  30-4-2020 13:51:05  1.0     BST200429   30-4-2020   28-4-2020
```

**Be aware that I had to clean your XML further and swap all parentheses (`"`) to single ones (`'`).**

Answer (score 2):

I've made a package for similar use case. It could work here too.

```
pip install pandas_read_xml
```

you can do something like

```
import pandas_read_xml as pdx

df = pdx.read_xml('filename.xml', ['FMPDSORESULT'])
```

To flatten, you could

```
df = pdx.flatten(df)
```

or

```
df = pdx.fully_flatten(df)
```